# MSVAD virtual driver loses audio packets for rendering in MS Windows 10 1703

Tags: windows, audio, driver, wdk

I wrote a virtual audio drivers on the base of MSVAD from WDK 8.0.  The driver worked on MS Win XP, Vista, 8.x and 10  well. But after start of Windows Creators Update (1703) I noted that a sound  began to lose and lagging on  my  driver.

I did some research and detected the following: the driver copied less audio data than my expected. For example:

CMiniportWaveCyclicStreamMSVAD::CopyTo() received 1920 bytes and CMiniportWaveCyclicStreamMSVAD::CopyFrom() sent  less audio data (1764)  on output. Why????

Please any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

I write a solution only for my project. Any case, this found bug helps you to fix your drivers too.

Cause:

My audio channel always has a stream with WAVEFORMATEX parameters: nSamplesPerSec = 44100  and nAvgBytesPerSec = 176400. In MS Win10 1703 the MSVAD driver changes the input parameters for the stream: nSamplesPerSec = 48000 and nAvgBytesPerSec = 192000. But the output parameters remain the same: nSamplesPerSec = 44100 and nAvgBytesPerSec = 176400.  So the driver receives 1920 bytes and sends out 1764 bytes. Hence, the driver loses 156 bytes of sound for each 10mS.

Solution:

Force the driver to select the parameters of the source: nSamplesPerSec = 44100  and the nAvgBytesPerSec = 176400. For it open the file kshelper.cpp and find the function GetWaveFormatEx().  Before `return pWfx;` add the checking:

```
if (pWfx->nSamplesPerSec != 44100)
{
    DPF_ENTER(("[%s] - FAIL",__FUNCTION__));
    return NULL;
}
else
{
    DPF_ENTER(("[%s]-ok",__FUNCTION__));
    return pWfx;
}
```

I hope that MS fixes that bug in the next WDK.